# I get 2 possibilities for one problem. In first one, x=y for an equation but in another one x is not equal to y for same equation. Why?

Tags: functions

Equation is

$$9x^2+6x-5=9y^2+6y-5$$

I was solving this to prove $x=y$ for one-one function. Although I proved it but here

$$ (x-y)(9x+9y+6)=0$$

Both sides can be divided either by $(9x+9y+6)$ to get the required answer i.e. $x=y$ or by $(x-y)$. On dividing both sides by $(x-y)$, I didn't get $x=y$.
So my question is why am I getting different answers although the equation is same?
Edit: $x,y$ belongs to domain i.e. positive real numbers and range of this function is $[-5,∞]$.

Comment: That function is not one-to-one, so it makes sense that you cannot obtain $x=y$.

Comment: In other words the relation $9x^2+6x-5=9y^2+6y-5$ does NOT define $y$ as a $function$ of $x.$ It only implies that $(y=x\lor y=-x-2/3).$

Answer (score 1):

You are getting different answers because there are two answers.
It is true that if $x=y$ then

$$ 9x^2+6x-5=9y^2+6y-5. $$

But it is also true that if $y = -\frac23 - x$ (that is, $9x + 9y + 6 = 0$) then

$$ 9x^2+6x-5=9y^2+6y-5. $$

The minimum value of $f(x) = 9x^2+6x-5$ is $-6$, when $x = -\frac13.$
Every other value greater than $-6$ is achieved for two possible values of $x$, one greater than $\frac13$ and one less than $-\frac13.$

Comment: But, in second one, x is not equal to y implies that function is not one-one

Comment: Why do you think the function should be one to one?

Comment: Sorry! My fault, I didn't mention the domain. By the I found it now where was I going wrong. Domain was positive real numbers and range was from -5 to infinity

Comment: It is positive infinity and negative 5

Comment: I wrote the previous comment (now deleted) much too quickly. Wrong in so many ways ...

Comment: The range isn't really what we need to know, it's the domain. And $x \in (0,\infty)$ means $-\frac23 - x \not\in (0,\infty)$. Another way to look at it is, if $x >0$ and $y >0$ then $9x+9y+6>0$, so $9x+9y+6=0$ is ruled out by the requirement that the input of the function is positive and only $x-y=0$ is left as a possible solution.

Answer (score 1):

The function in your question is NOT one-one if you consider it from $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$.

I think in the question you're solving, the function was defined on some other domain like let's say $(0,1)$ on which it is one-one. Note that it that domain, $9(x+y)=-6$ can never be true. So, you must have $x=y$.

Comment: Yeah! Thanks domain was positive real numbers and range was from -5 to infinity.

Comment: @GODofGamerZ The same logic applies then. You can never have $x+y=-\frac 69$ since $x$ and $y$ are both positive.

Comment: I think, you have mistaken. Correct will be $$x-y=0$$ and then $x=y$